# Inputbox and cases, cancel or closing the window

Tags: autoit

I'm new to autoit, and I'm wondering how to deal with some things. The code is simply this line :

```
$input = InputBox("game : +/-", "Write a number:")
```

---

If I write a number in the section, the program goes normaly.

If I click the cancel button, an error is thrown and so I dealt with it with :

```
    If (@error = 1) Then
        $End = True
```

Is what I ve done okay?

And :

- Could you please explain what is going on here and what exactly is happening if I enter no value or if I press cancel?
- If I close the windows, what happens ? I'd like the program to end.

Thank you very much ! Sorry if my question is easy or useless, I'll help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `InputBox` function values are returned to indicate the result of the process these are:

> Success:  the string that was entered.
>
> Failure:  "" (empty string) and sets the @error flag to non-zero.
>
> @error:   1 = The Cancel button was pushed. 2 = The Timeout time was
>   reached. 3 = The InputBox failed to open. This is usually caused by
>   bad arguments. 4 = The InputBox cannot be displayed on any monitor. 5
>   = Invalid parameters width without height or left without top.

So essentially that means that if it returns a non-empty string, the "success" case, you don't have to worry about `@error`. If any non-zero value is returned, the value of `@error` will indicate what has happened. So if in the case of an error you just want to return, you should use this if statement:

```
If (@error <> 0) Then
     $End = True
```

This works because we know if `@error == 0` then the input box has been successful and a value has been returned, otherwise we know it's thrown one of the errors listed above. I would anticipate that closing the window has the same effect as pressing cancel, i.e. `@error == 1` but I haven't checked.

Further to this, if you wanted to you could switch on the value of `@error` and use that to give the user an error message along the lines of "please enter a value" or "command timed out" but that seems more than is required in this instance.

---

Here's the relevant documentation: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/InputBox.htm

Good luck!

Comment: Actually, I read this (of course I did) ; why do you say that it can return true (just beneath the yellow square?) I don't see any situation where it gives "true"... And moreover, I don't think that closing the windows give an error == 1 because It is not working for me :(

Comment: @MarineGalantin sorry, I was tired when I wrote that answer. If it returns a non-empty string then you know it has been a success. You can always use an output box to show the value of `@error` when you close the window and see what happens. Sorry if you felt like I was having a dig for quoting the docs but you'd be amazed at how many people don't even google a question before asking...

Answer (score 0):

with a couple of ternary ops you can see that the cancel button sets the error flag and it does =1 or ==1 or =True (because True evaluates to 1)

```
$input = InputBox("game : +/-", "Write a number:")
$result = (@error == 1) ? 'cancel was pressed' : $input
msgbox(0, '' , $result = '' ? 'empty string' : $input)
```